# How to model a tinfoil hat? (aluminium foil texture as a mesh)

Tags: modeling

[image]

I want to model a tinfoil hat. What techniques should I use for modeling with tinfoil? I actually want the hat to be made of mesh (I don't want a texturing solution).

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You may achieve it randomizing the mesh a bit using simple modeling tools, but it demands some experimenting to make it look good.
[image]

Model the hat starting from a cube subdivided with a *subsurf modifier* (4-5 subdivisions). Apply the modifier. Subdivide the hat (with <kbd>W</kbd>-->*Subdivide*) to create a dense geometry. With the all vertices selected press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to *trangulate faces*. Unselect everything with <kbd>A</kbd>, go to *Select*-->*Random* (set it's value to about 30-50%), then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>-->*Rotate Edge CW*. It'll give a bit randomness to the mesh's vertices positions.
[image]

Grab selected vertices upwards (<kbd>G</kbd>,<kbd>Z</kbd>), then scale them outwards a bit (<kbd>S</kbd>). Crease the selected vertices with <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>. Add a *subsurf modifier* and *smooth* the mesh (<kbd>T</kbd>-->*Edit*-->*Shading*-->*Smooth*).
[image]

Finally to randomize the look of the hat even more, select some vertices and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>-->Smooth Vertex.
[image]

Comment: That's what they WANT you to think...

Comment: Another great modeling answer! I am always surprised by the way you can take a complex modeling job and break it down in to something so simple. In my mind modeling all those random creases, was too something too complex. Very well done.

Comment: Nice, quick to the point and includes gifs, images, and Screencast keys, good job.

Answer (score 6):

Here is a solution with more realistic render results (but be careful with the number of polygons, keep in mind how performant your computer is). Also with a mesh by applying the displacement.

- Add a Subsurf (of 4 or more if possible), Displace (Midlevel:0, Strength:0.04 depending on the texture), Solidify (**Keep that order in the modifier stack** from top to bottom)
- The displace should have an aluminium texture
- Unwrap your hat - In edit mode A (select all) then U (Unwrap) then Minimize Stretch option
- Apply the Subsurf then the Displace modifier
- No need to apply the Solidify modifier
- Decide if you Smooth the shading or keep it Flat
- Done

TIP: try to have a texture that does not have too many dark (reflection) areas, as this would result in a weird displacement. Mine comes from here https://www.shutterstock.com/pic-48906235.html

[image]

[image: Aluminium fold hat blender]
[image: Aluminium fold hat blender settings]

Comment: The only problem with this method is that if you zoom in, you can see the pixels

Comment: It depends on the size of your texture, on your level of subdivision, and in order to break the regularity you can use Triangulate modifier. If you use Smooth shading there are normally no "pixels" anyway.