# Aluminum Foil Texture

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, materials, node-editor

I'm trying to make the Payload Adapter Fairing of a Falcon Heavy rocket, which has a foil texture. I like what I have so far, but I think it could definitely use some work.

[image]

This is my node setup for the material, using an image of foil I found online.

[image]

This is the result I got; it looks a little better with good lighting, but the bump is still visible.

[image]
Here is the reference.

Comment: Could we see the normal map you are using? Considering that aluminium has a pretty consistent surface color, I think this entire effect could be done with displacement. Also - reflective stuff tends to look alot better with a full lighting setup/hdri.

Comment: Please use the [edit] link at the bottom of your question (https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXFuK.png) and add a reference image that might help us understand what the object is supposed to look like.

Comment: @GiantCowFilms no normal map, I used one image and set it to bump and texture

Comment: @cegaton done there is a refrence

Comment: Seems like you should be using normal (bump) and distortion mapping with a solid material color.

Comment: @Sparrowhawk Well, technically you used it to generate a normal map. Using actual displacement would produce much better results: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/71110/3127

Comment: NICE :-) I tried to do somthing like you at airbus, and it's very hard! I tried many different textures, scanned and with camera picture. Paper, aluminum fould and cling film din't worked, by now, I'm trying to scuplt it. Because MLI (The Satelite foil) hase a certian stifness, which is very hard to simulate!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this: use a distortion modifier and maybe some normal mapping and ditch the image texture all together.
Using this technique has the added benefit of being more realistic and because it's not BGE the performance shouldn't suffer too much.

[image]

Comment: I used displacement modifier, thank you for the tip. However, I used a texture other than the distorted one. Many thanks :)

Comment: but the problem of that texture, like I already use is, that it looks too flat, and also that there are areas which are completly flat. The charatacs of that foil is also, that the creases are note randomly, the follow the strucute below.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's realy important that you put the matalicness all the way up. this would mean that the matrial is treated like a metal witch makes it way more realistic. after that you can just use the map you are already using as a bump map. and than you can play with your roughness and specularity and see what you like.